# implementing NoSql of the Key-value type on a RDBMS

Tags: sql, nosql, key-value-store

If we implement NoSql of the Key-value type on a RDBMS (SQL DB), by only creating two-column tables, no constraints, no  additional indexes, etc.

Will its performance be similar to NoSQL DB's?

Answer (score 1):

depends what you mean by performance
writes?
reads?
horizontal scaling?
hosted where?

this question is very general...

Comment: Actually I meant for getting value by key, reading all, adding a pair to DB. but if you have already referred to scaling and storage, I would be happy to receive an answer to them too.

Answer (score 1):

No.  NOSQL databases are optimized for key-value lookups, so they automatically include an "indexing" structure.  This is likely to be a hash table rather than a B-tree index, but the idea is the same.  A SQL database with no indexes has no choice but to do a full-table scan (which might be a parallel full table scan), so the NOSQL database should be faster.

The appropriate comparison would be to a SQL database with a primary key on the `key`.  The performance of the NOSQL database *should* be a bit better than the SQL database, because NOSQL databases are (1) optimized for this particular usage pattern and (2) generally more relaxed about ACID properties.

However, performance on key-value lookups would not generally be the driving consideration for choosing between different technologies.  Other considerations such as query load, need for transactional integrity, scalability, recovery requirements would play a role in any decision.